# What impact do inhibitants have on H2O2 performance?

Tags: combustion, hydrogen-peroxide

How do the combustion characteristics, as well as the speed of decomposition, of inhibited hydrogen peroxide differ from those for pure H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub>. If a smoother combustion is achieved with pure hydrogen peroxide is it worth the explosion risk for the ease of combustion (if any advantage exists at all)?

Comment: different but related: [Does the Soyuz spacecraft use chemically stabilized hydrogen peroxide (H₂O₂) to remain ISS-dockable for 200+ days?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31337/12102)